# Firefox URL / link to a group of saved bookmarks?

Tags: firefox, macros, browser-tabs

In Firefox, you can easily save a group of tabs together. When (re-)accessing this group, the 'cascading' bookmark menu shows each individual bookmark (and under a line) it says *"**open all in tabs**"*

I'm looking for a way to launch those tabs without going up through the bookmark menu. Possible options:

1. Record a simple macro with any number of "superuser" utilities* ('1' is not the preferred option, since many 'little-macros' are hard to keep track of)
2. Use [AutoHotkey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AutoHotkey) (similar to option '1' and more flexible once you learn the basics).
3. **How does Firefox** load all those tabs? The information must be stored somewhere (as a type of URL?)

Quick Summary:

The moment I click on *"open all in tabs"*, I am clicking on something very similar to a hyper-link. How do I find the content (exact code) of that 'hyper-link', and / or *"How do I easily launch the tabs?"*

I'm looking for a way to launch those tabs without going up through the bookmark menu, **or** cluttering the bookmarks toolbar which I hide anyway  :o)

I tried to keep the question simple and not mention AutoHotkey programming. The objective is to launch all tabs using a button on an AutoHotkey GUI.

When grawity said, "It's just an ordinary folder containing ordinary bookmarks," he (she) reminds me I can easily find the folder / Now how to launch all the URLs inside that folder?

FYI:
(Basic-level) AutoHotkey works like this:

```
; Open one folder
ButtonWinMerge_Files:
Run, C:\Program Files\WinMerge\
Return
```

..

```
; Use the default web browser for one link
ButtonGoogle:
Run, http://google.com
Return
```

Question still open:

The moment I click on *"open all in tabs"*, I am clicking on something very similar to a hyperlink. *"How to 'replicate' the way Firefox launches the tabs with one click?"*

Comment: did you find a solution to achieve what you want to do? I'm having the same question and I am interested in a practical answer.

Comment: Not yet, also still looking.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm looking for a way to launch those tabs without going up through the bookmark menu.

Save them to Bookmark Toolbar. Then click with the middle button of your mouse to open all tabs.

> c) How does Firefox load all those tabs? The info must be stored somewhere (as a type of URL??)

It's just an ordinary folder containing ordinary bookmarks.

> The moment I click on "open all in tabs", I am clicking on something very similar to a hyper-link. How do I find the content (exact code) of that 'hyper-link'?

The "Open in all tabs" menu item is part of Firefox itself. It's not a hyperlink, has no URI or "content", and it is shown for *all* folders, not just ones saved that way.